# What is meant by "RAW" firmware?

Tags: rom-flashing, restore, device-firmware, stock-rom, asus-zenfone-2

I want to use [Asus Flashtool](http://www.asus-zenfone.com/2015/12/download-asus-flashtool-10014-for-windows.html) to restore stock firmware to my phone. The download page says I will need "RAW" firmware. What exactly is that? I have already downloaded the correct firmware file from Asus' own website. The [site in question](http://www.asus-zenfone.com/2015/12/download-asus-flashtool-10014-for-windows.html) has a link to what it refers to as "RAW" firmware, but I would rather flash the firmware I've downloaded from an official source. Is there any difference? Is "RAW" firmware supposed to be something special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAW is just the archive format used by the Asus flasher (as opposed to ZIP, EXE, IMG, KDZ, etc.). If you're using the Asus flash tool (AFT) and you downloaded a `.raw` file, you should be all set. AFT does not support other formats.

If you want to install the stock firmware as it comes from the official source (Asus website), then you wouldn't use AFT. The exact procedure you would use varies depending on what you've got installed now and if it will boot.

Comment: I didn't download a any `.raw` file though. The official firmware file is a `.zip` file (if extracted it gives a number of files and folders.) I suppose I need to download the `.raw` file. But where can I get it from a reliable source?

Comment: You posted another question about how to flash back to stock. Since this question is just about RAW, I've answered that here and will attempt to answer the other question separately.